# s3fsとsambaを利用したファイルサーバーにMacから利用できない

Tags: macos, amazon-s3, samba

同じ状況・解決された方がいましたら返信いただけますでしょうか。

Centos6の環境にs3fsを利用して、AWSのs3をマウントしたサーバーを用意し、
マウントしたディレクトリをsambaで共有設定を行う構成を作成しました。

windowsでアクセスをした際は問題なく操作が出来ますが、
Macから接続した際は、カスタムアクセス権が割り当てられているせいか、
「内容を表示するためのアクセス権がないため、フォルダ”〜〜”を開けませんでした」と表示されてしまいます。

Macのいくつか前のOSからはACL周りで変更があったという記事（リンク参考）
を見かけましたが、ファイル自体は外部サーバーのものになるので異なるような気もします。

- http://blog.majili.com/mac/becomes-impossible-to-change-or-delete-files-on-a-mac/
- http://lab.flama.co.jp/archives/668/

---

以下の2点の現象からS3のディレクトリの権限が、sambaを利用すると権限が想定した動作をしないようです。

- sambaでアクセスを許可しているディレクトリ直下にあるファイルは読み書き権限があるようです。
  それを考えるとs3のディレクトリの権限に問題があるように感じます。
- Macで接続した状態でディレクトリを作成すると、作成したディレクトリへの読み書き権限があることが確認できましたが、
  再度マウントすると権限がなくなってしまいます。

---

なお、s3を通さない通常のsambaのみのアクセスはwindows,Mac両方から正常に動作しております。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

s3fs は現在は使っていないのですが、オーナーやパーミッションが維持されなかったと思います。
他に、s3ql というものもあって、こちらの方が UNIX, Linux 的には混乱なく使えると思います。

Comment: samba について、smb.conf の log level を上げて、ローカルと S3 での違いを調査してはどうでしょうか。
log level は 1つずつ上げて、たくさん出すぎるようならクラスを絞っていくと、わかりやすいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

同様の環境を用意できないので勘ですが、`smb.conf` で `nt acl support = no` にして NT 互換 ACL を無効にしてみるとどうでしょうか。

また、以下のページによると `unix extensions = no` が効くようです。

- s3fsを利用で困ったこと - Qiita

  - http://qiita.com/pingpong/items/dccc221e95e0b1c5a3d3